# Do Asian koel males communicate through calls?

Tags: ornithology, ethology, bioacoustics

Male Asian koels are heard making long [koo-Ooo](http://www.xeno-canto.org/sounds/uploaded/QEWWQFASQH/XC353944-Asian%20Koel1.MP3) s  which are returned by [similar koo-Ooo s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_HW81szhm8&t=33s)<sup>1</sup> from some far away place. While the female makes short [shrills](http://www.xeno-canto.org/sounds/uploaded/GULGAACSCS/XC252829-Asian%20Koel.mp3).

I never had the opportunity to see the other bird and find out its sex. But it sounds just like the first one.

Is it actually communicating with a male bird? What is the known reason if so?

<sup>**1**</sup> The reply calls (to be found around 0:29) in the video are really low.

**Note:**

1. A singing male bird also gives desperate accelerated calls when  mimicked.
2. Its breeding season has just begun in India and this communication can be heard.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular species of bird, but males of numerous species call throughout their territory to inform other males of their territory. This is especially true of migratory birds that move in and out of areas (with recently sexually mature males now trying to find their own territories and fighting for limited space) "Responses" could very well be males in nearby territories doing the same thing. Just a thought...

Comment: Also, I don't hear any response in the video you link to -- it just sounds like echoes of the male in front of the camera. Are you referring to that sound, or is there another call I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Still working on this question and the following are the findings:

1. The male bird when mimicked possibility mistakes the mimic as an intruder in its territory and so it gives louder & accelerated calls.

> The *male while defending* its territory gradually approaches its adversary, hopping from twig to twig *calling loudly* and displaying its threatening posture. ( [B S Lamba (1969)](http://biostor.org/reference/148970/page/2) )